# postgresql streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

My environment consists of two RHEL7 nodes such as following:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
# uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 27 16:01:21 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q postgresql
postgresql-9.2.15-1.el7_2.x86_64
#
```

I'm trying to follow [Streaming Replication - PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication#How_to_Use).

Step 12:

primary:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -c "SELECT pg_current_xlog_location()"
 pg_current_xlog_location 
--------------------------
 0/1C000318
(1 row)

-bash-4.2$
```

standby:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -c "select pg_last_xlog_receive_location()"
 pg_last_xlog_receive_location 
-------------------------------
 0/1D000000
(1 row)

-bash-4.2$ psql -c "select pg_last_xlog_replay_location()"
 pg_last_xlog_replay_location 
------------------------------
 0/1D000080
(1 row)

-bash-4.2$
```

Please advise.

Comment: So what is your question?  The slave does not catch up?  The replayed segment is newer than the received, so I guess it just works fine.

Comment: standby should never be ahead of primary, no?